# Locating column of dataframe in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, apply, fillna, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe in a dataframe similar to this one (my real one is much larger)

```
df_peter = pd.DataFrame({"height": [50,np.nan,65], "weight": [20,25,27]})
df_anna = pd.DataFrame({"height": [47,55,np.nan], "weight": [18,23,30]})

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Peter", "Anna"], "Year":[2000, 2002], "Data":[df_peter, df_anna]})
df
```

```
    Name    Year    Data
0   Peter   2000    height weight 0 50.0 20 1 NaN ...
1   Anna    2002    height weight 0 47.0 18 1 55.0 ...
```

my final goal is to use the `.fillna(method = "ffill")` function on the height column of Peter and Anna,
so i need a way to locate these two height columns
would be also practical to plot the data

using `.fillna(method = "ffill")` for one row is easy

```
df.loc[0,"Data"]["height"].fillna(method = "ffill")
```

But for both/all rows is not that easy beacause: `df["Data"]["height"]` doesn't work
actually i found a solution writing this question:

```
df["Data"].apply(lambda x: x["height"].fillna(method = "ffill", inplace = True))
```

but is there a way to do this without apply and lambda?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use a loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    df.loc[i,"Data"]["height"]=df.loc[i,"Data"]["height"].fillna(method = "ffill")
```

Comment: works but im searching for a simpler way because I have to use this very often in a way larger dataframe to work with the data (ploting, creating filters, manipulate data, ...)
a one line solution that also allows assigning would be greath